# Ionic - change/remove default (cordova) boot logo

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building a hybrid app with the Ionic framework.

I have problems changing the default app-icon and "boot-screen" on Android. I've added a custom icon.png and splash.png to /resources. After that, I ran `ionic resources` but the default icon/screen is still there. I've removed the app from my device, rebuilt it etc.

Any ideas?

Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.palabi969346" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>xyzApp</name>
  <description>xyzDescription</description>
  <author email="xyz@email.com" href="xyz-app.com">xyzAuthor</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
  </platform>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.4"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
  <!--<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>-->
</widget>
```

[image: Default boot screen]

Comment: Have you looked inside the `resources/ios/icon/` or `resources/android/icon/` folders or any other folder for that matter? I have had many instances of `ionic resources` showing output, but not actually generating a splash screen or app icon. So please check those folders and make sure that the generated files look like your app icon and splash screen, otherwise the problem is with `ionic resources`.

Comment: how was this solved ? @Brotzka

Comment: I don't know. This question is over 3 years old. Sorry @sij

Comment: @sij: You may want to change the style in `www/css/index.css`, specifically the `.app`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the **splash screen** on your Ionic App.
Here you can find the entire documentation to modify this:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html

During the build process, Cordova (v3.6 or later) will look through the project’s config.xml file and copy the newly created resource images to the platform’s specific resource folder. For example, Android’s resource folder can be found in `platforms/android/res`, and iOS uses `platforms/ios/APP_NAME/Resources`. The files located here, are correct?

Greetings.